# Publish a post in specific time php

Tags: php, cron

I searched how can I publish a post on specific time in the future, I found Cron jobs... But I want user to choose the time when the post should be published. Like we want publish a post in Facebook.
How can I do this? I using PHP.
Thanks

Comment: For `in Facebook` you will need `CRON`, if it is your own site...Set the time on the post and have the DB showing posts in order from newest to oldest (`where active = 1 and datepublished <= now() order by datepublished desc`). Then when the time this article should be active it will be at the top of the page (or in order with other articles set for that same time).

Comment: I think there is no way without Cronjob for php. You can set cronjob for every minute. 
So cronjob script will search all post those publishing time current minute and then it will publish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cron` is still a tool to use for this, you just need to structure your use of that tool to what it's suited to do.  Consider the following scenario:

- User submits a "post" and a future date/time to your application.
- Your application saves this in your application's database.
- Every X minutes, a `cron` job on your server runs, which:

  - Polls the database for "posts" which have not been sent
  - Checks if it's time to send them
  - Sends the resulting "posts"

So your "application" is essentially two applications sharing the same database.  One is the web application with which your users interact, the other is the `cron`-scheduled application which integrates with the external system (e.g. Facebook).